# How to show custom Toast in pecific position in a Activity in Android

Tags: java, android

I need to show a customize toast in android. Which will show in a specific position.How can i show a custom toast in a specific position of screen.

Comment: as a suggestion if you want toast to be displayed in various positions you can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37668673/6312749

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1. create a layout custom_toast.xml with TextView like bellow

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="800dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_tost_shape"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Action Successfuly Completed!"
    android:textColor="#ff0000" 
    android:textSize="40sp"/>
```

2. Insert this code to show the toast in a method that will take message as parameter. myShowToastMethod(String message){//code}

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = GenApplicationId.this.getLayoutInflater();
             View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, null);
             TextView tvMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             tvMessage.setHeight(100);
             tvMessage.setText(message);
             Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
             toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
             toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, -0, 230);
             toast.setView(view);
             toast.show();
```

Comment: I like your answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can use this library

SuperToasts Library

[SuperToasts in github](https://github.com/JohnPersano/SuperToasts)

Answer (score 0):

From the [android developer guide:](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

First get your application/activity context, define the message string and duration, create a new Toast object and pass it the context, text message and duration, call show().

You can position your toast with the setGravity function, called prior to toast.show():

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this methods

```
public static void showBottomToast(Context context, String msg) {
    View custom_view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
            R.layout.dialog_bottom_toast, null);

    TextView tvMessage = (TextView) custom_view
            .findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
    tvMessage.setText(msg);

    showToast(context.getApplicationContext(), Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL
            | Gravity.BOTTOM, custom_view, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}

public static void showToast(Context ctx, int gravity, View root,
        int duration) {
    final Toast mToast = new Toast(ctx);
    mToast.setGravity(gravity, 0, 0);
    mToast.setDuration(duration);
    mToast.setView(root);
    mToast.show();

}
```

and dialog_bottom_toast.xml is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/marg_20"
    android:text="@string/welcome"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_16"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very Easy Method to implement Custom Toast

```
//show custom Toast in android
    private void showCustomToast(String showToast) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(showToast);
        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
    }
```

Define it's layout as
toast_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And wherever you want to call this then just call it as

```
 showCustomToast("Your_Message");
```